# Why has president Erdogan suddenly decided to mend relations with Israel?

Tags: international-relations, israel, turkey

Why has president Erdogan suddenly decided to mend relations with Israel?

What kind of advantage is he looking for?

Is he looking for a favor from the USA or assistance from Israel's defense industry?

**N.B.** I am talking about post-Navi Marmara relations.

Answer (score 4):

Your questions is off. Turkey and Israel have enjoyed great relations from day one. It is only recently that this has changed at all.

> Israeli–Turkish relations are the bilateral ties between the Israel
> and the Republic of Turkey. Israel–Turkey relations were formalized in
> March 1949,[1] when Turkey was the first Muslim majority country to
> recognize the State of Israel.[2][3] Both countries gave high priority
> to military, strategic, and diplomatic cooperation, while sharing
> concerns with respect to the regional instabilities in the Middle
> East.[4][5] However, relations between the two countries have
> increasingly deteriorated in recent decades.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel%E2%80%93Turkey_relations

Comment: I am talking about post-Navi Marmara relations.